# PHP usort equivalent to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a multi-dimensional array which needs sorting. The array is something like this:

```
$array[0] = $key1[0]['date']$key2['title']
$array[1] = $key1[0]['date']$key2['title']
$array[2] = $key2['title']
```

Each array item may have multiple dates ($key1[0]['date'], $key1[1]['date'], etc) or none at all. When present, the date is something like: 2015-10-04T00:00.

I save strtotime($key1[0]['date']) and key2['title'] of each array element in a mysql table and then order it like so:

```
(CASE WHEN date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC, date ASC
```

I need to replicate the results directly in the array, perhaps using usort(); the $key1[0]['date'] is the key for sorting, which may not exist.

The rule should be that if the date is in the future, it should order it ascending (the closest being the first) and if the date is in the past, it should order it descending. If there is no date at all, it should put such entries in the middle (between the future and present).

For example, if today is 2015-10-04, it should sort:

1. 2015-10-05
2. 2015-10-10
3. 2015-12-01
4. no date set
5. no date set
6. 2015-10-03
7. 2015-09-01

Thanks.

Comment: this raise exception `$array[0] = $key1[0]['date']$key2['title']`

Comment: So the right code for the array should be $key1[0]['date'][$key2]['title']. But lets get the demand right.

Do you want to be enabled to sort on key2?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I need to enable sort on key1[0] (sort by date ascending for future dates, descending for past dates and entries with no dates should be in between).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution. It might not be the best solution but it does work as expected.

```
<?php

# The array of dates
$dates = array('2015-10-05', '2015-10-10', '2015-12-01', '2015-10-03', '2015-09-01', 'invalid date', '');

# I shuffle the array as it will be in disorder - you want to remove this line
shuffle($dates);

# I save the todays timestamp into a variable
echo '<pre>'; print_r($dates) ; echo '</pre>';
$now = time();
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'), $now);
echo 'Today is: ' . date('Y-m-d', $now) . '<br>';

# Define the buffers
$before = array();
$undef = array();
$after = array();

# Loop through all dates
foreach ($dates as $i => $date):
  # Get the timestamp for the date X
  $time = strtotime($date);

  # Check if timestamp lies before or after today or is undefined
  if ($time === false || $time === -1):
    $undef[] = $date;
  elseif ($time <= $today):
    $before[] = $date;
  else:
    $after[] = $date;
  endif;
endforeach;

# Sort both arrays by value (descending per default)
sort($before);
sort($after);

# Here we make the dates that lie before today ascending
$before = array_reverse($before);

# Some output - you can ommit these lines
$sorted = array('after' => $after, 'undefined' => $undef, 'before' => $before);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($sorted); echo '</pre>';

# This will merge all three arrays together - this is the final result
$result = array_merge($after, $undef, $before);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => invalid date
    [1] => 
    [2] => 2015-10-03
    [3] => 2015-10-10
    [4] => 2015-12-01
    [5] => 2015-09-01
    [6] => 2015-10-05
)

Today is: 2015-10-04

Array
(
    [after] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-10-05
            [1] => 2015-10-10
            [2] => 2015-12-01
        )

    [undefined] => Array
        (
            [0] => invalid date
            [1] => 
        )

    [before] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-10-03
            [1] => 2015-09-01
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => 2015-10-05
    [1] => 2015-10-10
    [2] => 2015-12-01
    [3] => invalid date
    [4] => 
    [5] => 2015-10-03
    [6] => 2015-09-01
)
```

You can test it here: [php tester tool](http://phptester.net)